# tkcalendar is installed correctly, but it gives an error when executing the command from tkcalendar import Calendar. What is the problem?

Tags: python-3.3, tkcalendar

I installed tkcalendar-1.6.1.tar.gz on Python 3.3.2 (32-bit) via command prompt environment with python setup .py install command. But when executing the command `from tkcalendar import calendar`, we encounter the following error.

[image: this error]

I also installed lower versions of tkcalender, but I still faced the same problem.